# API error sending webhook in Discord (DiscordJs/NodeJs). [InvalidType]: Supplied options is not an object

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Discord.Js API version: 14.6.0
Node.Js version: 18.12.1

The code is only intended to send a Webhook message using a specific username, specific avatar, and specific name, obtained from variables. This code worked perfectly in previous versions of Discord.Js. This is part of the code I'm currently using:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [
  GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
  GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
] });
const { EmbedBuilder, WebhookClient } = require('discord.js');
const { Webhook } = require("discord.js");

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
   
  if(msg.content == 'send') {

msg.channel.fetchWebhooks()
      .then(hooks => {  try { 
        console.log('1');
        setTimeout(sodps, 350)
        function sodps () { let wwebhook = new WebhookClient(thisID, thisTOKEN)
        wwebhook.send(thisCONTENT, {
        
          username : THISusername, 
          avatarURL : THISavatarURL
  
      
      }) }} catch(err) {
          
        } }).catch(console.error);

}

});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
E:\Documents\PF2.0\project falido\projectkypartner\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:18
      throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.InvalidType, 'options', 'object', true);
      ^

TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at new BaseClient (E:\Documents\PF2.0\project falido\projectkypartner\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:18:13)
    at new WebhookClient (E:\Documents\PF2.0\project falido\projectkypartner\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\WebhookClient.js:44:5)
    at Timeout.sodps [as _onTimeout] (E:\Documents\PF2.0\project falido\projectkypartner\CACHE\oindex.js:4198:44)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  code: 'InvalidType'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I've tried a lot, I couldn't resolve or understand exactly what Discord is asking. If anyone can help me, I'll be grateful!

I also tried something like:

```
wwebhook.send({
    content: THIScontent,
    username: THISusername,
    avatarURL: THISavatarURL,
    
});
```

And other variations (adding or recommend "embed: [thisEMBED]", among others), several similar tests according to the sites I accessed. nothing worked; the error remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebhookClient` constructor now takes an object with both the ID and token in the first parameter. You'd want to do something like

```js
new WebhookClient({ id: thisID, token: thisTOKEN })
```

instead.